# Access webpack require.context from dev server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

I have a webpack dev config that I use to server a mocked backend with express. Something like this example form [DevServer Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveronaftersetupmiddleware):

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
      if (!devServer) {
        throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined');
      }

      devServer.app.get('/setup-middleware/some/path', (_, response) => {
        response.send('setup-middlewares option GET');
      });
    },
  },
};
```

But instead of directly serving there I load and initialize another file that will attempt to search for every file with 'mock.js' in the name and load them. For that I plan to use `require.context` since it is a webpack feature. But everytime I try to do this I get that context is **undefined**.

I try to load them like this:

```
const context = require.context('../src/', true, /\.mock\.js$/);
const mocks = context.keys().map(context);
```

Is there a way to implement this feature back in? (Or at least have an alternative) I have been looking around but it seems that not many people have had my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
if (typeof require.context === 'undefined') {
  require.context = (
    base = '.',
    scanSubDirectories = false,
    regularExpression = /\.js$/
  ) => {
    const files = {};

    function readDirectory(directory) {
      fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach((file) => {
        const fullPath = path.resolve(directory, file);

        if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
          if (scanSubDirectories) readDirectory(fullPath);
          return;
        }

        if (!regularExpression.test(fullPath)) return;

        files[fullPath] = true;
      });
    }

    readDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, base));

    function Module(file) {
      return require(file);
    }

    Module.keys = () => Object.keys(files);
    return Module;
  };
}
```